# How to store dynamically generated form different fields values back to database php mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am beginner in php mysql and I have a problem below picture type of form how to save values of all rows or only selected row fields values:- 
name of fields are as :-

```
  foreach($data as $row){
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="$row['ProductID']" name="productID[]" /></td>
  <td>     <input type="text" value="$row['Quantity']" name="quantity[]" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" value="$row['Price']" name="price[]" /></td>
 </tr>
}
```

[image]

**1. Question is How to get only selected row fields value in php or jquery**
I have no Idea how to get only selected row fields value in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get a listing of all your items with a note whether selected or not, just change your form names a bit (If I understand what you are looking for...):

```
<?php 
    $data[] =   array('ProductID'=>123,"Quantity"=>1,"Price"=>"2.00");
    $data[] =   array('ProductID'=>234,"Quantity"=>2,"Price"=>"1.50");
    $data[] =   array('ProductID'=>345,"Quantity"=>1,"Price"=>"4.59");
    $data[] =   array('ProductID'=>456,"Quantity"=>4,"Price"=>"1.99");

    foreach($data as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product[<?php echo $row['ProductID'];?>][select]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?>" name="product[<?php echo $row['ProductID'];?>][qty]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Price']; ?>" name="product[<?php echo $row['ProductID'];?>][price]" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

**Gives you:**

```
// Just loop through the [product] array looking for the 'select' = 'on' 
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [123] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 2.00
                )

            [234] => Array
                (
                    [select] => on
                    [qty] => 2
                    [price] => 1.50
                )

            [345] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 4.59
                )

            [456] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 4
                    [price] => 1.99
                )
        )
)
```

**To get the selected items:**

```
if(!empty($_POST['product'])) {
    foreach($_POST['product'] as $row) {
            if(!empty($row['select'])) {
                    print_r($row);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but can you please write code for  how to loop through on select

Comment: Same way you do with the table: `foreach($_POST['product'] as $row){...etc.`

Comment: Thanking you again but pardon me I really do'not know how to collection only selected row fields value will u please write full code only for selected row it can be one or more ?

Comment: See my update. You should be able to do whatever you are looking to do with that.

Comment: if I do print_r($row[qty]) its shows undefined index because I want each field value of  a particular row like checkbox value qty value price value ?

Comment: Maybe paste an edit on your question to what you have so far. It's hard to tell what you mean.

Comment: Can I put ProductID in each input name  tag  ?

Comment: ok Thanking you I have got the solution thank you very much again